# array declaration in this.state React

Tags: reactjs

**I'm trying to create an array with 5 values which I could use with nameArray[number].
I think that the declaration of the array is wrong but I don't know how I can fix it.
My idea is that: I have 5 buttons, when I click one of this, only one value of the 5 values in the state array change from false to true.
**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeButtons: [false, false, false, false, false]
    };
  }

  cliccato = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const number = parseInt(e.target.id);

    this.setState(
      {
        activeButtons: !this.state.activeButtons[number],
      },
      () => {
        console.log(" "+ this.state.activeButtons[number]);        
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration of the array is fine. You can make it shorter with `Array(5).fill(false)`.

It's setting state part that needs work. In your current code, you are setting the state to the alternate of a boolean value, instead you need to set it to an array.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  activeButtons: prevState.activeButtons.map((val, index) => {
    if(index === number) {
      return !val;
    }
    return val;
  })
}));
```

Also, using the [functional set state form](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate) here

Answer (score 2):

You're updating your state's `activeButtons` with a single boolean value, rather than an updated array.

You need to generate a new array and modify only the relevant element:

```js
const newArray = [...this.state.activeButtons];
newArray[number] = !newArray[number];

this.setState({
  activeButtons: newArray,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're overwriting `activeButtons` every time with only one element value. You need to preserve the other values each time you want to update an element.

Using an `Object` would be a more graceful data structure in this case though.

```
this.setState(
  {
    activeButtons: {
        ...this.state.activeButtons
        [number]: !this.state.activeButtons[number]
  }
)
```